# In QTP, suppose there are number of tabs opened in the same browser, How can i activate and open a particular tab in the browser?

Tags: qtp

I had tried with many methods,but i couldn't do it and also "obj.Opennewtab","obj.Navigate"  methods are also not working.Please help me out in this with an example.

Answer (score 0):

Tabs are identified by QTP as `Browser` test objects (actually for a [rather good reason](http://h30499.www3.hp.com/t5/The-Future-of-Testing-Blog/Understanding-the-web-test-object-model-in-HP-Unified-Functional/ba-p/6168133)).

If you perform any activity on on a `Browser` test object (include `Navigate` and any operations on sub elements) it will activate the tab in question. The question is how do you identify the tab you want.

e.g.

```
 Browser("title:=.*Google.*").Navigate "www.bing.com"
```